# Using class constants in PHPUnit annotations

Tags: php, laravel-4, phpunit, eloquent

The manual of PHPUnit shows, that I can use class-constants in annotations for @expectedExceptionCode, see [PHPUnit @expectedExceptionCode](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.expectedExceptionCode)

I try to use it within my name spaced model which extends from Eloquent.
When I run my tests I got an: "PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Eloquent' not found"
Running the App is all fine, so it depends on the Unit-Tests, isn't it?

Any ideas?

```
namespace Foo\Models;

use \Eloquent;

class Bar extends Eloquent {
    const ERRORCODE = 150;

    ...
}
```

---

```
class BarTest extends TestCase {

    /**
     * @expectedExceptionCode       Foo\Models\Bar::ERRORCODE
     */
    public function testFoobar()
    {
        $name = 'foobar';
        Bar::findBarOrFail($name);
    }
}
```

For clarification:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Eloquent' not found in PathToProject/app/models/Bar.php
```

---

### Update

After @j-boschieros comment I got the above code working! Thanks mate!

However, when I provoke the exception in a controller test, the fatal error still occurs.

Even if I use the namespaces or not.

```
use \Eleoquent;
use Foo\Models\Bar;

class TestController extends TestCase {

    /**
     * @expectedExceptionCode       Foo\Models\Bar::ERRORCODE
     */
    public function testStoreActionWithInvalidDatatyp ()
    {
        $this->call('POST', '/routeToException');
    }
```

---

### Update 2

Got my Unit-Tests working when I extend \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model instead of Eloquent.

```
namespace Foo\Models;

use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Bar extends Model {
    const ERRORCODE = 150;

    ...
}
```

This differs from [Laravel Doc](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#basic-usage). Is it still okay?

Comment: Do you pull phpunit as a composer package or is it global executable?

Comment: It is global executable.

Comment: So check if it uses `phpunit.xml` from your laravel root. It seems it doesn't bootstrap the app.

Comment: How about discarding the `use` and try: `class Bar extends \Eloquent {` ?

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk phpunit.xml from laravel root is used. I've tested it with the color-attribut.

Comment: @DanFromGermany I've tried it, but same error occurs.

Comment: Seems you are missing autoloader then.

Comment: I think @JarekTkaczyk or @DanFromGermany could be right.

If it's simply that you need to update the autoloading, you can `php composer dumpautoload`. If it's an issue with bootstrapping then you'll need do add `bootstrap="bootstrap/autoload.php"` (or the path to wherever your `autoload.php` file is relative to your `phpunit.xml` file) to your `phpunit.xml`.

Comment: Please note my update

Answer (score 0):

The "class" `\Eloquent` is actually an alias which is registered at run-time by the Laravel framework. You're making PHP parse the model class file before these aliases have been set up, causing it to fail. The correct approach to this is just to avoid the global namespace aliases and use the real class names instead (`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` instead of `Eloquent` in your case). You can find a list of class aliases in `app/config/app.php`.